# How to get an Object containing the value of one key of Duplicates as a key where the value for each key is a collection of the duplicates

Tags: javascript, duplicates, javascript-objects, collect

basically, for now I got :

- a list of duplicates [{},{}] base on the key = 'Email'
- an object of the email list and the count of every email :

  ```
     { 
      email1@email1.com: 2,
      email2@email2.com: 4,
      email3@email3.com:2
      }
  ```

from the code

```
    let countObj = {};
    let key='Email'
    let countFunc = key => {
      countObj[key] = ++countObj[key] || 1;
    }
     matchDuplicates.map(dup=>dup['Email']).forEach(countFunc);
```

- an array with the duplicates remove, so a collection of unique objects with the code:

  ```
  const key='Email'
  const arrayUniqueByKey = [...new Map(matchDuplicates.map(item =>
    [item[key], item])).values()];
  ```

and I would like the actual objects on the right key, example:

```
    { 
      email1:[
        {name: 'john', age:32, Email: 'john@companyName1.com' , company: 'companyName1'}, 
        {name: 'john', age:32, Email: 'john@companyName1.com' , company: 'companyName1'}
      ],
      email2:[
        {name: 'peter', age:40, Email: 'peter@email.com', company: 'companyName2'}, 
        {name: 'peter', age:39, Email: 'peter@email.com', company: 'aPreviousCompanyName'}, 
        {name: 'peter', age:38, Email: 'peter@email.com', company: 'aPreviousCompanyName'}, 
        {name: 'peter', age:40, Email: 'peter@email.com', company: 'companyName2'}
      ],
      email3:[
        {name: 'nina' , age: 28, Email: 'nina@companyName3.com', company: 'companyName3'},
        {name: 'nina', age: 28, Email: 'nina@companyName3.com', company: 'companyName3'}
      ]
    }
```

with pure JS only, no package.

why? because it is a very messy data base with very different keys from one to the other

Answer (score 0):

```
    let arrayEmail = matchDuplicates.map(dup=>dup['Email'])
    let bigObj={}
    
      arrayEmail.forEach(eachEmail =>{ 

        let smallArray=[]
        return matchDuplicates.forEach(eachObj=> {
        if(eachEmail.match(eachObj['Email'])){
            smallArray=[...smallArray,eachObj]
    
            return bigObj= {...bigObj, [eachEmail]: smallArray} }
             })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't test this yet:

```
let countObj = new Map();
let key='Email';

/** creates a reducerFunction based on given key */
let duplicateReducer = (key) => (accumelator, currentVal) => ( 
     accumelator.set(currentVal[key], 
       [
          ...(accumelator.get(currentVal[key])||[]), 
          currentVal
       ])
   )
/** creating a reducerFunction for "Email" */
const duplicatedKeysReducer = duplicateReducer(key);
countObj = matchDuplicates.reduce(duplicatedKeysReducer,new Map())
```

Or without Map:

```
let countObj = {};
let key='Email';

let duplicateReducer = (key)=> (accumelator, currentVal) => ({
    ...accumelator
    [currentVal[key]]:[
     ...(accumulator[currentVal[key]]||[]), 
     currentVal
  ]})
const duplicatedKeysReducer = duplicateReducer(key);
countObj = matchDuplicates.reduce(duplicatedKeysReducer,{})
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, I haven't tried that either, since I found my answer but it might help someone else